# Buildings for Affine groups

Tags: buildings, classical-groups

Let $G$ denote one of the classical groups over a finite field. Is there a natural way to associate a building to the affine group $V\rtimes G$, and an analog of the Solomon-Tits theorem?

Comment: What is $V$? some particular representation?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of GL(V), O(V), Sp(V)... where V is a vector space of the right dimension.

Comment: Of course you can associate a building to it, namely the building of the group $G$, with $V$ acting trivially on it. It even satisfies Solomon-Tits. But you probably want something else, e.g. $V\rtimes G$ acting transitively on it, with kernel of the action contained in the center?

Comment: It's hard to answer your questions without more details. But both spherical and affine Moufang buildings of rank at least 2 resp. 3 are classified, and their automorphism groups are not of the form you ask. If you want Solomon-Tits to hold, though, it ought to be a spherical building, and then the answer to your question is probably "no"... But again, it's not quite clear to me what the question is, exactly. Perhaps you can elaborate a bit? What do you want to do with that hypothetical building?

Comment: To be more precise I am referring to an analog of the Steinberg representation for the Affine group as studied in "The Affine Group I. Bruhat Decomposition" by Solomon, and also possible extensions to the other groups O(V), Sp(V). I think this representation is also defined by Lusztig.